# fileChannel exception in flume

Tags: flume

> org.apache.flume.ChannelException: Put queue for FileBackedTransaction
>   of capacity 1000 full, consider committing more frequently, increasing
>   capacity or increasing thread count.

Could you advise me what to do to resolve ?

Comment: You probably need to increase the transaction capacity.

Comment: Thanks.  I have increased the transaction capacity more than batch size then the issue was resolved.